# Google BigQuery timestamp comparison

Tags: google-bigquery, bq

there is a table "tbl1", having columns "name, surname, log_date".
"log_date" is `timestamp` type.

How can I retrieve the records logged yesterday?

I am struggling with `timestamp` variable, I did something like:

```
declare yesterday timestamp
set (yesterday) = select TIMESTAMP_ADD(EXTRACT(Date FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), interval -1 day);
```

Above fails, so I am not able to use it later in my script:

```
SELECT distinct 
    name
FROM 
    `xxx.tbl1`
WHERE 
    log_date > yesterday
```

Also I tried:

```
SELECT 
    distinct name
FROM 
    `xxx.tbl1`
WHERE 
  log_date > TIMESTAMP_ADD(EXTRACT(Date FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), interval -1 day)
```

or

```
SELECT 
    distinct name
FROM 
    `xxx.tbl1`
WHERE 
  log_date > Select TIMESTAMP_ADD(EXTRACT(Date FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), interval -1 day)
```

or

```
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT EXTRACT(Select TIMESTAMP_ADD(EXTRACT(Date FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), interval -1 day) AS CustomDay
)
SELECT distinct 
    distinct name
FROM 
    `xxx.tbl1`, vars
WHERE 
    log_date > CustomDay
```

No luck.

Is there any other way, how to parse yesterday's date and use it in the select statement later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the error you are getting, it seems that the problem is that you are trying to compare a `timestamp` (the `log_date`) with `datetime` (the extracted `DATE`). This should work:

```sql
SELECT 
    distinct name
FROM 
    `xxx.tbl1`
WHERE 
  DATE(log_date) = DATE_ADD(EXTRACT(DATE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

**Important:** Use `=` for comparison to get the logs from yesterday only, `>` will get you the logs from today onwards.

One little thing: I would use `DATE_SUB` to subtract days instead of `DATE_ADD` with `-1` (for readability), but kept it like that because of your example code.

Comment: oh, I was sure there must be something pretty simple. Thank a lot, saved my day :)